# Passing using anonymous functions polymorphically

Tags: go

As far as I can tell, when passing a function as an input into another function it must have an identical contract - not allowing for the ability to leverage interfaces as follows: (runnable example here: https://play.golang.org/p/LXvNgziDdgp)

```
package main


func main() {
    foo(processS1)
}

type I1 interface {
    bar()
}

type S1 struct {
}

func (s1 S1) bar() {
}

func processS1(s S1) {
}

func foo(func(I1)) {
}
```

from a type-system perspective, the assumed issue is that a *function* type is passed, and not an interface. but, I can't see what the issue would be with allowing the type system to infer the relationship here. I believe I've seen this in other languages.

Any reason as to why Go can't/won't support this?

Comment: For the same reason Go does not have variant types, or covariant result types, `func(S1)`  and `func(I1)` are different things, which are  not necessarily interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short the relationship you've defined there is not valid in any typed language.

You've defined foo as a function that takes a type func(I1). func(S1) is a different type. The complexities of the relationships between these types is more complex than simple inheritance. The golang team has chosen simplicity over solving for function type and signature matching.

One way these complexities become apparent is you've actually defined the relationship backwards. Imagine there was an struct s2 that also implemented I1. Also, s1 had a method baz().

If foo passed in S2{} to the function parameter it would implement I1, but processS1 would call a function that doesn't exist on the passed in struct.

runnable: https://play.golang.org/p/EvwQpCXhqTb

Even if you swapped the types (https://play.golang.org/p/ItUx5pRJ6-g), which would be able to run without panics, it still wouldn't work in golang. As to why golang doesn't try to solve these problems, I'm not sure you'll get a satisfactory answer. The team responds to these kind of questions with general philosophical views such as:

> The simplicity of method matching is a feature of the language.

I do think your question here does help justify that view though. It's a complex the problem is hard to reason about. It's easier to just not solve it than add additional complexity.